# Using Python codecs causes readline problems with sys.stdin?

Tags: python, codec, subprocess

I am writing a Python wrapper script (childscript.py) for a command line executable (childprogram).  Another executable, (parentprogram) spawns childscript.py and pipes output into childscript.py.  childscript.py spawns childprogram with:

```
    retval = subprocess.Popen(RUNLINE, shell=False, stdout=None, stderr=None, stdin=subprocess.PIPE)
```

If childscript.py does a series of reads from sys.stdin straight up using readline:

```
line = sys.stdin.readline()
```

I am able to get all the output from parentprogram and feed it into childprogram.

However, if I try to use the codecs module by doing:

```
sys.stdin = codecs.open(sys.stdin.fileno(), encoding='iso-8859-1', mode='rb', buffering=0)
```

or do a:

```
sys.stdin = codecs.getreader('iso-8859-1')(sys.stdin.detach())
```

and attempt to do the read, the read does not get all the output from parentprogram.  If I force additional output from parentprogram, the missing bits come out along with part of the additional output that I pushed in.  It looks like childscript.py is not reading everything that it is being provided to it when I use the codecs module.

Am I doing something totally wrong?  Without the codecs, childscript.py triggers an exception when presented with iso-8859-1 encoded stuff from parentprogram.

EDIT:
I discovered that Python v3.x "open" can take the encoding option as well.  I changed the line to use "open" instead of "codecs.open":

```
      sys.stdin = open(sys.stdin.fileno(), encoding='iso-8859-1', mode='r')
```

and it works as expected, without any of the problems that open.codecs produces.  I've switched my script to use "open" instead.

If anybody can explain why the codecs module behaves differently, I'd appreciate it.

Answer (score 1):

Flush the output channel in the parent.

Pipes are always buffered. The usual buffer size is 4KB. Unlike when the output is connected to the console, the standard runtime will not flush the output for you after each line.

Comment: I've been assured by the developer of the parentprogram that the buffers are getting flushed.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
import sys
import os

fd = sys.stdin.fileno()
text = ''
while 1:
    try:
        raw_data = os.read(fd, 1024)
        text += unicode(raw_data, 'iso-8859-1')
        # now do something with text
    except (EOFError, KeyboardInterrupt):
        break
```

This way you avoid using `readline()` which will issue an error for non-ascii characters, but still can use non-blocking read.

The only problem is that you have to separate the input into lines yourself.